# NSURL image from URL iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception

I'm getting error while getting image from url for some images, and again for other images not.

```
NSURL* imageURL = [[API sharedInstance] urlForImageWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [photo objectForKey:@"src"]] andID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.IdPhoto]];
```

In API

```
- (NSURL *)urlForImageWithName:(NSString *)imageName andID:(NSString *)imageID
{
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@upload/%@", kAPIHost, kAPIPath, imageName];
return [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
}
```

src is name of the image in database and it works for most photos, even for all when I'm loading them in tableView, but when I press on image and want to show it fullscreen, some images are loaded and some throw exception: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0x...).

HELP !!!!

Comment: Which line is the bad access being thrown on?

Comment: first code I wrote, NSURL* imageURL....

Comment: What is the 'photo' object and does it really exist (has it been released)?

Comment: are you loading image in customcell? in tableview

Comment: Some object my be released, go to step by step and find at which line it crash..

Answer (score 0):

Things to check

1. is the method defined in .h file of Api class
2. Shared instance created properly.

Include

```
- (NSURL *)urlForImageWithName:(NSString *)imageName andID:(NSString *)imageID;
```

in .h

Check shared instance by logging its memory

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[API sharedInstance] description]);
```

If you get error in this log the problem is with what you created a shared instance

UPDATE

From the comments what you are trying to achieve is different .For your purpose you have to load the images in tableview asynchronously.For this purpose you can simply use libraries like

- [AsynchimageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)
- [SDWebimageview](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
- [AFNetworking Extension](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

etc

Comment: everything is fine with that... i even check image name before calling urlWithImageName and name of image is good. And again it fails 2/10 pictures.

Comment: ok do one thing log the string you create in methods and find if any return null

Comment: I log in API in urlWithImage... method but that method doesn't even get called. Just stops right at NSURL *imageURL...

Comment: well include the code of singleton and method where it breaks completely in question

Comment: the thing that bothers me is - why it works with some pictures and others not ? does it have to do with data of photo, or maybe photo size ? because it works perfectly with some photos...

Comment: I'm assigning every image a target action for pushing big picture view in cellForRowAtIndexPath and I think there is the problem.